# Writing file from array is generating extra blank lines

Tags: php, windows

Here is my function:

```
function writeFile($array, $package_date) {
    $filename = "loadpkg-" . $package_date . ".txt";
    $package = fopen($filename, "w");
    $header = "File\n" .
              "Batch Comment: Load - " . $package_date .  
              "\nRECORDS\n";

    fwrite($package, $header);

    foreach ($array as $id) {
        fwrite($package, $id);
    }

    fclose($package);
}
```

When the output file is opened in Notepad it seems to ignore the newline characters in my $header variable. When the output file is opened in Sublime, the $header variably displays as expected but there are blank lines between each written array element.

It might also be helpful to note that the text file I am originally reading from to create the array that gets written also contains blank lines when opened in Sublime but not Notepad. I would like the format for my output file to be standard throughout, without any empty blank lines.

Here's an example of how the original array is created:

```
if (substr($line, 0, 2) == "1,") {
    $line = str_replace("1,", "TEST", $line);
    array_push($array, $line);
}
```

Comment: How are you reading from the file? The strings returned by `fgets()` include the newlines.

Comment: Try using the `PHP_EOL` constant instead of `\n`, it ensures you get the correct newline encoding for the OS.

Comment: notepad doesn't show newlines, it shows `\r\n` though.  notepad++ FTW!

Comment: I am using fgets() but only lines that begin with "1," are pushed to the array which is why I am confused.